# show first ul that have li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple question
I have a list like this

```
<div class="ullist">
  <ul></ul>
  <ul></ul>
  <ul></ul>
  <ul>
    <li>child1-1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>child2-1</li>
    <li>child2-2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

And it is set with css to hide all uls within div.  I want to unhide the first ul that has children li's.
How to do this with jquery correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.ullist').children('ul:has(li)').fist().show()
```

Comment: You should modify that to `$(".ullist").children('ul:has(li)').first().show()` so only the first ul that has an li gets shown. (I also added the selector for the parent element)

Comment: Man, you are all over it today.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan home alone on a holiday :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why did you delete your answer, i was looking to delete mine

Comment: @ArunPJohny you got there first, and I was waiting for you to edit.

Answer (score 6):

How about,

```
   $('li:first').parents('ul').show();
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/34/)**

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('ul').children('li:first').show()
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, the `ul` would be hidden so the `li` wouldn't be visible

Answer (score 0):

This shows only the first ul that has li's

```
$(".ullist ul").hide()
$(".ullist").find("li").first().parents('ul').show()
```

see jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sWjNF/1/